# What does "Ojo con los hombres" mean in this context?

Tags: traducción

Here is the context in the book I'm reading "Mirta y El viejo señor" by Soler-Espiauba:

> Qué bueno que encontraste un trabajo. ¿Es serio ese señor don
>   Francisco? Ojo con los hombres, mi niña, que hasta viejos son todos
>   igualitos. El sueldo me parece bueno, claro que seguramente allá la
>   vida está más cara, tú hablas de pesetas, yo pienso en pesos, pero no
>   tienes gastos adicionales de arrienda31 , ni de luz, ni de agua ...

Comment: Creo que es una advertencia sobre la actitud de los hombres (de cualquier edad) con las mujeres, respondiendo a la pregunta sobre la seriedad de Don Francisco.

Comment: "ajá", como ten cuidado. Veré si se conforme con el contexto.

Comment: "Keep an eye on [that danger]" in this case danger = horny guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Ojo con* means *be careful with*, or *beware of*. So the meaning of that sentence is something like:

> Beware of men, my girl. No matter their age they're all alike.

Comment: Like the salary is too good to be true. He wants something else.

Comment: @user135711 I see it just as a word of caution in general. The sentence about the salary is entirely positive, I don't see it as related to the previous observation.

Comment: Yes, reading it more closely, I think the quid pro quo maybe I introduced. Just don't trust men.